# jQuery - .show not working after .hide

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do I get "pastButton" to only show "pastInvestments" and "currentButton" to only show "currentInvestments" when clicked on?

In my html I have 2 buttons and 2 divs:

```
<button class="w3-button currentButton">Current</button>
<button class="w3-button pastButton">Past</button>

<div class="currentInvestments">
   //images inside div
</div>

<div class="pastInvestments">
   //images inside div
</div>
```

I want "pastInvestments" to be hidden by default on page load, and when "pastButton" is clicked only "pastInvestments" images show. Right now the "currentButton" is working perfectly but the "pastButton" hides BOTH "pastInvestments" and "currentInvestments" when clicked.

Here is the jQuery I'm using :

```
$(function() {
    $('.pastInvestments').hide();

    $('.currentButton').click(function(){  
      $('.currentInvestments').show();
      $('.pastInvestments').hide();
    });

    $('.pastButton').click(function(){  
      $('.currentInvestments').hide();      
      $('.pastInvestments').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: I think we'd need to see more context, since this appears to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/nLoy8gcw/

Comment: My guess is you have a problem with your HTML, and you're missing a `</div>` between `currentInvestments` and `pastInvestments`.

Answer (score 0):

Hide the .pastInvestments in CSS if you want it to be hidden at page load:

```
.pastInvestments {
display:none;
}
```

This way it loads hidden instead of hiding it after page load.

It works fine for me btw.

Comment: This is basically the same as the `.hide()` call he does at the beginning, except you won't see the element momentarily when the page loads. It's not the solution to the problem he's having (which no one seems to be able to reproduce).

Comment: It's better practice because the div won't flash, but I'm not able to reproduce the problem either.

Comment: Answers are supposed to solve the problem, not just provide unrelated programming advice. Use a comment for things like this.